# Bot framework Directline -Change Bot name Run time

Tags: c#, .net, botframework, bots, direct-line-botframework

Is it possible to change the name of the  bot during runtime. Current the name which i have added in portal is getting displayed under bot message. Is it possible to update it in run time rather than displaying the name configured in portal.

Comment: "displayed under bot message" do you mean in the webchat channel?

Comment: yes @jsonsowers

Answer (score 1):

You can [intercept all messages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/dotnet/bot-builder-dotnet-middleware?view=azure-bot-service-3.0) that are exchanged between user and bot, and you can check the value of `activity.From.Name` to detect if the message sent from your bot, and then you can specify a new value for `activity.From.Name` property, which would help achieve your requirement to show updated display name in webchat.

```
public async Task LogAsync(IActivity activity)
{
    if (activity.From.Name== "fehanbasicbot")
    {
        activity.From.Name = "testbot";
    }
}
```

**Test result:**

*My bot settings:*

[image]

*In webchat:*

[image]